RJSF anyOf customization
Let's say I have a JSONSchema like this:
{
  type: "object",
  anyOf: [
    {
      properties: {
        a: {
          const: "x",
        },
      },
    },
    {
      properties: {
        a: {
          const: "y",
        },
        b: {
          type: "string",
        },
      },
    }
  ],
}

And when I specify uiSchema like the following:
{
  anyOf: [
    {
      a: {
        "ui:widget": "buttonGroup",
      },
    },
    {
      a: {
        "ui:widget": "buttonGroup",
      },
      b: {
        "ui:widget": "phone",
      },
    },
  ],
}

RJSF doesn't respect what I specify in "ui:widget" fields but renders "select" widget instead. How can I specify custom widget for rendering of such conditional fields? Is it possible at all in case of such json schema definition?
